# getting syntax error while using LIKE in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-connector-python

When I create sql query like this:

```
param = (date, )
query = SELECT date_added from deploy_requests WHERE date_added LIKE '%s %'
query.execute(query, param)
```

i get Syntax error

but if I use the not recommended way

```
query = SELECT date_added from deploy_requests WHERE date_added LIKE '{} %'.format(date)
```

Comment: @KenWhite I tried `param=date` doesnt work and `LIKE '%s %' ` %s is date is correct... %s is date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, this is how I did it.

```
def get_deployment_times(date):
    date = "{}%".format(date)
    param = (date, )
    query = "SELECT date_added from deploy_requests WHERE date_added LIKE %s"
```